# open xml file with nokogiri update node and save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm trying to figure out how to open an xml file, search by an id, replace a value in the node and then resave the document.

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <user id="1370018670618">
      <email>1@1.com</email>
      <sent>false</sent>
    </user>
    <user id="1370018701357">
      <email>2@2.com</email>
      <sent>false</sent>
    </user>
    <user id="1370018769724">
      <email>3@3.com</email>
      <sent>false</sent>
    </user>
    <user id="1370028546850">
      <email>4@4.com</email>
      <sent>false</sent>
    </user>
    <user id="1370028588345">
      <email>5@5.com</email>
      <sent>false</sent>
    </user>
</data>
```

My code to open and find a node

```
xml_content = File.read("/home/mike/app/users.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_content)
node_update = doc.search("//user[@id='1370028588345'] //sent")
node_update.inner_html ##returns value of "sent"
```

the part in this where I'm stuck is actually updating the node. `node_update.inner_html = "true"` returns a method error on `inner_html`. then after that saving the updated file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, your `node_update` is actually a [`NodeSet`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet), not the [`Node`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node) that you probably think it is. You need a `Node` if you want to call `inner_html=` on it:

```
node_update[0].inner_html = 'true'
```

Then writing out the updated XML is just a bit of standard file manipulating combined with a `to_xml` call:

```
File.open('whatever.xml', 'w') { |f| f.print(doc.to_xml) }
```

---

As an aside, your input isn't valid XML. You have a `</details>` but no `<details>`.

Comment: oh wow.  node_update[0] was the issue!  thank you for helping.  it all worked perfectly.

i removed the trailing </details>. that was from an earlier version.